# Написать программу (python)

Tags: python

Напиши программу, которая будет спрашивать пользователя, сколько было пончиков и сколько всего ребят, и выводить первой строкой количество пончиков, которое достанется каждому ребенку, а второй - количество пончиков, которое будет подарено учительнице.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
a = input("Enter amount of students: ")
b = input("Enter amount of donuts: ")

try:
    print(int(a)%int(b))
    print(round(int(a)/int(b)))

except ValueError:
    print("Enter numbers not words!")
```

Comment: `print(divmod(int(a), int(b)))`